# P2P using web browser

Tags: browser, client-server, p2p

I've been told that some torrent sites like BITLET or MININOVA allow you to download from other users, and obviously other users to download from you while you have your browser open.

I would like to create something similar for a game, where:
 1. User A and B are connected to a specific website
 2. User A knows the IP and port of B
 3. User A starts downloading some information from user B

Could anyone give me some tips or keywords to start?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=browser+p2p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your game would have to be written as a browser plugin since browsers don't support this kind of thing. It looks like BITLET uses java, which would work, or FLASH 10 also supports socket connections so that would be another alternative. You'd probably want to have a central server to keep track of what different peers are available. Each client could connect to the server, get a list of clients, then create tcp socket connections to each client it wants to connect to. Each client could then additionally tell each other about other clients, and so on.